# Android: IntentService getting terminated

Tags: android, service, intentservice, background-service

I have a `IntentService` which runs forever as I am using a infinite while loop. However, when I close my application the service gets terminated. Maybe I am wrong, but as far as I know, the `IntentService` should run in background until it finishes the task.

Moreover, as I am using infinite while loop, the service should run forever. But clearly this not what is happening.

```
public class TaskNotifierService extends IntentService {

    public static final String TAG="TaskNotifierIS";

    public TaskNotifierService(){
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        while(true){
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            String currentDay=null;

            switch(day){
                case 1:
                    currentDay="Sunday";
                    Log.i("currentDay","Current day is: "+currentDay);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    currentDay="Monday";
                    Log.i("currentDay","Current day is: "+currentDay);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    currentDay="Tuesday";
                    Log.i("currentDay","Current day is: "+currentDay);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    currentDay="Wednesday";
                    Log.i("currentDay","Current day is: "+currentDay);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    currentDay="Thursday";
                    Log.i("currentDay","Current day is: "+currentDay);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    currentDay="Friday";
                    Log.i("currentDay","Current day is: "+currentDay);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    currentDay="Saturday";
                    Log.i("currentDay","Current day is: "+currentDay);
                    break;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Can somebody explain, what is going wrong in here?

Comment: The answers below are correct. However if you have an action that needs to be executed periodically, you should schedule it using `AlarmManager`. Using an infinte loop is bad practice and will cause battery drain.

Answer (score 2):

`IntentService` is designed to process an incoming intent and stop immediately after. So in your case I strongly recommend you to replace `IntentService` by `Service`.

Both Service and IntentService will be killed while the application is killed, you can register a WatchAlarm in service `onCreate` function to start self in a controlled period. You can check the code below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    registerWatchAlarm();
}

private void registerWatchAlarm() {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent startSelf = new Intent(this, BoostBallService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, startSelf,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + WAKE_UP_TIME_INTERVAL, WAKE_UP_TIME_INTERVAL, pi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android can kill any app process at any time without warning.  It has a priority system by which it decides which processes get killed first.  Having a service active doesn't prevent your process from getting killed, especially if it has no visible UI.

You can read more [details about the priority system here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).  Start at the following text:

> The Android system tries to maintain an application process for as
>   long as possible, but eventually needs to remove old processes to
>   reclaim memory for new or more important processes.